# how can i use MultiValues map in cucumber step

Tags: java, regex, cucumber

This is my step defination grammer on Cucumber -

the following fields are newly populated on (Vet Out|Vet Enriched) message with expected value$
| domain   | VET                  |
| version | CLIENT_INSTRUCTION   |
| host    | 1                    |

and it picks the table data in map.

now i have to provide multivalued map <String, List> for
| domain   | VET, abc, xyz |

Can anyone please share the regular expression for that

Comment: Please, add more data, how to reproduce the process, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a recent version of Cucumber JVM this works with no further configuration:

```
  Scenario: datatable transform
    Given a multi-value map
      | key1 | value1 | value2 |
      | key2 | value3 | value5 |
      | key3 | value4 | value6 |
```

```java
    @Given("a multi-value map")
    public void aMultiValueMap(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
        // prints: {key1=[value1, value2], key2=[value3, value5], key3=[value4, value6]}
        System.out.println(map);
    }
```